# Eigenvalues of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I'm looking for the eigenvalues of the following symmetric tridiagonal matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
a & z & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
z & b & z & 0 & 0  \\
0 & z & 0 & z & 0  \\
0 & 0 & z & c & z  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & z & d  \\
\end{pmatrix}

which is a real symmetric Jacobi matrix. I know that its determinant is given by the continuant of its elements but I was wondering if any of you knows some papers or links in which I can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix.

My goal is to compute the exponential of this matrix, which is why I'm trying to diagonalize it.

Comment: Its characteristic polynomial is a quintic with sufficiently general coefficients that you can't expect a simple factorization. Is there a specific reason for computing exactly the exponential of this matrix? Would numerical methods be enough?

Comment: Do you know any of the values a,b,c,d,z? If yes, please give them to us.